# Replacement with regex or anything else in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text, replace

I want to manage data that I receive from multiple parties and convert it into structured data in order to have unity in our system.

For example, I receive data like this:

1. nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm
2. nominal diameter 10 mm
3. for external diameter 15mm
4. head dm 9.00 mm
5. diameter 208/20 mm height 218 mm

The goal is to retrieve in order this output

1. M1-13x0.5
2. M10
3. M15
4. M9
5. M208/20 H28

I thought I would do it with multiple regexes like and then replace it

```
df['diameter'] = df['New_size'].str.findall('^nominal diameter\s([\S]+)\sx\s([\S]+)\smm$')
df['diam2'] = 'Nom.M'+df['diameter'].str[0].str[0]+'x'+df['diameter'].str[0].str[1]

df['diameter'] = df['New_size'].str.findall('^nominal diameter\s([\S]+)\smm$')
df['diam2'] = 'Nom.M'+df['diameter'].str[0]
```

But this only helps when searching for diameter, In example 5 I need to run it again and join somehow to also add height…

Is there a way how to loop through data and replace like in Excel + regex for regex?
Or is my plan completely stupid and there are much better ways how to do this?

I thought of plan to split everything into pieces and replace word after word.
and then joining only those info I think is necessary. but really it seems I am too complex
Thasnk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this type of editing, you cant be absolute the first time especially if the df is big and has diverse text. Go staged.

**Option 1:** Replace patterns rather than target substrings

replace values in df. First replace all alphas except x followed by space and before digit with nothing. Then from start of string replace all Non digits before numeral. Then replace all dots followed by 2 zeros

```
df['text_edited'] = df.replace(regex={'[a-wy-z]+\s(?=\d)': 'H', '^[\D]+(?=\d)': 'M', 'mm': '', '.00':''})

     

                   text                text_edited
0    nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm    M1-13 x 0.5 
1            nominal diameter 10 mm            M10 
2        for external diameter 15mm             M15
3                   head dm 9.00 mm             M9 
4  diameter 208/20 mm height 218 mm  M208/20  H218
```

**Option 2:** Replace target substrings

I assume your main aim is to replace diameter and height with initials. Do that and if there are any unwanted residuals that significantly change the attribute meaning, edit the new column further

```
df['text_edited'] = df.replace(regex={'diameter\s|dm\s': 'M','height\s': 'H','[^MHx0-9\W]':' ', '.00':''})



df['text_edited'] = df['text_edited'].str.strip().str.replace('^[x]','', regex=True)



                    text                 text_edited
0    nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm      M1-13 x 0.5
1            nominal diameter 10 mm              M10
2        for external diameter 15mm              M15
3                   head dm 9.00 mm               M9
4  diameter 208/20 mm height 218 mm  M208/20    H218
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way how to in regex or any other make the condition to change diameter to M only if after diameter are some decimal places? If I use: "diameter\s\d" and make it as replace then I also replace the number but that I dont want.
Or maybe if I expand that I always want diameter followed by digit and mm => then to change to M"digits" - is it possible in this solution? THANKS!!!!

Comment: Give a sample output of what you refer to here

Comment: I have for example: nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm 
here I want to change it to M1-13x0.5

but if I have nominal diameter BLACK 1-13 x 0.5 mm. I dont want to change diameter to M BLACK 1-13 x 0.5. I want to replace diameter only if after diameter is numeric and it ends with "mm" => then I need to retrieve what is between diameter and mm.

Basically to have "if" if there is diameter following with digits and mm, I want to change it to Mdigits. If it is not followed, I dont want to do anything with that.

Comment: got it: (?<=diameter\s).*?(?=\smm)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use a sequence of regular expressions:

```
df['new_col'] = (
    df['col']
    .str.replace(r'.*nominal diameter ([\d-]+) x ([\d.]+) mm.*', r'M\1x\2', regex=True)
    .str.replace(r'.*nominal diameter ([\d.]+) mm.*', r'M\1', regex=True)
    .str.replace(r'.*for external diameter ([\d.]+)mm.*', r'M\1', regex=True)
    .str.replace(r'.*head dm ([\d.]+) mm.*', r'M\1', regex=True)
    .str.replace(r'.*diameter ([\d./]+) mm height ([\d.]+) mm.*', r'M\1 H\2', regex=True)
)
```

Output (before):

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'d':['nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm','nominal diameter 10 mm','for external diameter 15mm','head dm 9.00 mm','diameter 208/20 mm height 218 mm',]})
>>> df
                                col
0    nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm
1            nominal diameter 10 mm
2        for external diameter 15mm
3                   head dm 9.00 mm
4  diameter 208/20 mm height 218 mm
```

Output (after):

```
>>> df
                                col       new_col
0    nominal diameter 1-13 x 0.5 mm     M1-13x0.5
1            nominal diameter 10 mm           M10
2        for external diameter 15mm           M15
3                   head dm 9.00 mm         M9.00
4  diameter 208/20 mm height 218 mm  M208/20 H218
```